# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute method

Tags: python, django

I know this question has been asked many times, but I haven't found any solution that solved my problem. Basically, I have a method inside a class view in Django, and that method calls another method, which raises an `AttributeError`: `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'send_email'`.

This is the code:

```
class PartyListView(ListView):
    # ...
    # ...

    def approve_party(self, party_id):
        returnObj = {}

        # get the party by id
        party = party_repo.get_party_by_id(party_id)
        if party is None:
            returnObj['message'] = "The requested party doesn't exist."
            jsonObj = json.dumps(returnObj)
            return HttpResponse(jsonObj, status=404, content_type="application/json")

        # change the status to Approved
        party.party_status = Core.PartyStatus.Approved
        party.save()

        # email the party team on the approval
        self.send_email(True, party)

        # return a json success response
        returnObj['message'] = "The party has been approved."
        jsonObj = json.dumps(returnObj)
        return HttpResponse(jsonObj, status=200, content_type="application/json")

    def send_email(self, isApprovalEmail, party):
        username = self.request.user.username
        from_email = username + "@example.com"
        recipient_list = [party.host.student_email]
        cc = ['admin@example.com']

        if isApprovalEmail:
            subject = "APPROVED Party Registration for {}".format(party.party_time)
            body = "approval email"

            email = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list, cc=cc)
            email.send()
        else:
            subject = "REJECTED Party Registration for {}".format(party.party_time)
            body = "rejection email"

            email = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, recipient_list, cc=cc)
            email.send()

    # ...
    # ...
```

I have tried the following things:

1. Rearrange the order of the method `send_email`: Above `approve_party`, below, at the top, at the bottom.
2. Rewrite the whole file in another editor without copying anything.
3. Use PyCharm's convert indents to spaces option to make sure indentation is good.
4. Write other dummy functions in the class and try to call them from `approve_party` - none of them works.

Here's the full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/parties/approve/151
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:/Programming/Party-Reg\admin_dashboard\views.py", line 93, in approve_party
    self.send_email(True, party)
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'send_email'
[05/Dec/2017 18:07:19] "GET /admin/parties/approve/151 HTTP/1.1" 500 17786
```

And `approve_party` is registered in `urls.py` as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...,
    url(r'^parties/approve/([0-9]*$)', views.PartyListView.approve_party, name="Approve Party"),
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated the question with the full traceback.

Comment: Please show the code that is calling `approve_party`

Comment: @Alasdair just posted `urls.py` where `approve_party` is registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using class based views incorrectly. Class based views should be registered with the `as_view` method.

```
url(r'^parties/approve/([0-9]*$)', views.PartyListView.as_view(), name="Approve Party"),
```

However, in this case, it looks as it would be simpler to make `approve_party` and `send_email` regular functions instead of methods of your view.

```
def approve_party(request, party_id):
    returnObj = {}
    ...
    send_email(request, True, party)

    return HttpResponse(jsonObj, status=200, content_type="application/json")

def send_email(request, isApprovalEmail, party):
    username = request.user.username
```

Then change your URL pattern to:

```
url(r'^parties/approve/([0-9]+$)', views.approve_party, name="approve-party"),
```

I suggest using `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]*` to make sure that the URL includes at least one digit, and I would avoid using spaces in URL pattern names.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just curious, why didn't my code work? I did register my class-based view as you told, and it seems like the class has a `send_email` function. Why didn't Python recognize that?

Comment: `PartyListView.approve_party` is not a bound method. When you use it in your URL pattern, `self` is the request instead of the view instance, so you get the attribute error. Switching to use `as_view()` will fix that, but there’s no code that calls the `approve_party` method.